# Only two tasks run concurrently in asynchronous dispatch queue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm trying to run three concurrent tasks that each take ~30 seconds. However only two will run at the same time, and the third task waits for one of those to complete before it begins.

My current code:

```
func sliderMoved(_ label : UILabel, openCharacteristicNum : Int, closeCharacteristicNum : Int, sender: UISlider, sliderTimer:Timer){

    //run this on a background thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        var actuatorPosition = self.getActuatorPosition(label)

        if (actuatorPosition < sender.value) {
            // stop closing (if it was) and start opening
            self.writeValue(closeCharacteristicNum, value: 1, withResponse: false)
            self.writeValue(openCharacteristicNum, value: 0, withResponse: false)

            while actuatorPosition < senderValue && sliderTimer.isValid{
                actuatorPosition = self.getActuatorPosition(label)
            }
            // stop opening
            self.writeValue(openCharacteristicNum, value: 1, withResponse: false)
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried creating a concurrent queue and running three tasks within that queue, but still only two run concurrently. I've also tried creating three separate concurrent queues and running one task in each, but still had the same problem.

My only guess is that I'm hitting a hard thread limit that iOS allows the app to use, seeing as each task completely blocks the thread until complete.

Comment: I would not call it a problem. You need to think more about the semantic that's needed for your particular case / logic you need to implement. Based on that some questions that could guide you are: 1 - do si need to wait for all of them to finish? 2 - how much prioritize do each one of them have. With the answers to this questions you could choose to use other strategies as dispatch groups for example, or dependencies between operations, or changing the QOS required level for example

Comment: I ended up using timers to regularly monitor actuator position, rather than monitoring as fast as possible with a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Multicore iOS devices only have 2-cores with 1-thread each, so the limit is 2-threads at once. The only exception is the iPad Air 2 which had 3-cores.

Edit:
This is no longer the case. Since A10 it has been 2 big and 2 or 4 small cores. As far as I know, Apple's A-series still only support one hardware thread per core. That said, libDispatch will manage the thread pool for you and it should pick the optimum number of threads for the iOS device it is running on, the number of hardware threads available is a low level detail that you shouldn't worry about when using libDispatch.

Answer (score 0):

> but still had the same problem

Except that there is no "problem" here.

> My only guess is that I'm hitting a hard thread limit that iOS allows the app to use, seeing as each task completely blocks the thread until complete

I wouldn't describe it as a "hard" limit, but there could be a limit. The point, however, is that there are no guarantees about anything so you shouldn't have any expectations one way or another. The whole point of GCD is that you concern yourself with *queues* and allow the kernel to allocate *threads* as it sees fit. And that is exactly what it is doing. You scheduled operations on the queue and they eventually got performed. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: If the problem is that you need to perform some action when and only when all three operations have completed, GCD provides ways to do that. But trying to guess about how operations will be threaded, let alone depending on it, is just silly and pointless.